# -3 + -3 = -2 in two's complement

Tags: binary, addition, twos-complement

using 4-bit numbers calculating -3 + -3 in two's complement, my calculation yields -2.

3 in binary is 0011

making both one's complement by flipping all the digits since both are negative

1100 && 1100

adding one to them, since we are using two's complement

1101 + 1101 =

11010

first one is overflow, and are tossed away in two's complement. So are left with 1010, which is minus two in decimal. Can someone explain what is done wrong in this process?

---

**EDIT**

My problem seems more specifically how to interpret the result of a two's complement calculation. I treat the result as following:

The result is 1010.
In my world, the first bit is a sign bit, indicating that the number is negative.
The following 0 means there is 0 of -4's
the following 1 means there is 1 of -2's
the following 0 means there is 0 of -1's

therefore, I interpret it like the result is -2

Comment: Nothing is wrong. `1010` is `-6`, which is the correct answer. `1110` is `-2`.

Comment: could you elaborate why that is, and post as answer? In my head, the first bit is sign bit, and 010 is 2 in decimal?

Comment: According to your logic `1101` should then be `-5` but you said it yourself that it's `-3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct, you just interpreted it wrong.  When you perform arithmetic on numbers in two's complement, the result is also two's complement.  So the conversion from negative to positive is done the same way as the conversion of the original numbers from positive to negative.

Given the 4-bit binary value `1010`, first flip the bits for one's complement to get `0101`, then add 1 for two's complement to get `0110`.

`0110` is 6, so `1010` is -6.

Comment: could you elaborate on the rule of converting the result of the calculation to decimal, and I will mark it as the answer. It seems there is a point I still quite can't figure out.

Comment: @JonasGrønbek I think I spelled it out pretty well.  What part are you confused about?

Comment: I interpret the answer as a normal binary number with a sign bit. 
So, the first 1 indicates it is negative, the following 0 means that there is 0 of -4's, the following 1 means there is 1 of -2 and the last 0 means there is 0 of - 1's :)

Comment: @JonasGrønbek The answer is in two's complement, just like the numbers that were added to create it.  So you do two's complement conversion to go back from negative to positive.

Comment: @JonasGrønbek As specified in the answer, which is the same way you converted 3 to -3 in the question.

Comment: flipping all the bits and adding 1?

Comment: @JonasGrønbek Yes, exactly.

Comment: But now the result is positive, shouldn't it in the end evaluate to 1110? and not 0110?

Comment: @JonasGrønbek That just tells you what the positive equivalent is so you know what you're reading.  `0110` is 6, so to get -6 you do two's complement conversion:  `0110` -> `1001` -> `1010`, which is what you got.  The conversion goes both ways.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

> first one is overflow

If, as you imply here, you are restricting your storage to a single nybble, then with two's complement, you can represent values in the range `-8` to `7`.

`-2` would then be `0b1110`, which is not what you have. `-6` is indeed `0b1010`, which is the correct sum.